# avr-objcopy.exe - Application Error when compiling in arduino IDE (Win8.1.1 Pro 64-Bit)

Tags: arduino

When I click compile I get this:

> "avr-objcopy.exe - Application Error
>
> The instruction at 0x0044c2e5 referenced memory at 0x0044c2e5. The memory could not be written.
>
> Click on OK to terminate the program."

Followed immediately after by this:

> "WerFault.exe - Application Error
>
> The instruction at 0x67272a49 referenced memory at 0x00000001. The memory could not be written.
>
> Click on OK to terminate the program."

What is causing this? How do I fix it? I really need this code to compile, it's for my brother's birthday. Code in question is:

```
//**************************************************
//
// Test of playtune library for Arduino NANO
//
// L. Shustek, 31 Jan 2011, initial release.
// L. Shustek, 27 Feb 2011, new score data
//
//**************************************************


#include <Playtune.h    

// Playtune bytestream for file "happy_birthday.mid" created by MIDITONES V1.6 on Mon Aug  4 08:55:29 2014
// command line: miditonesV1.6.exe -t3 happy_birthday 
byte PROGMEM score [] = {
// Happy Birthday
4,176, 0x90,60, 1,194, 0x80, 0x90,60, 0,150, 0x91,41, 0x80, 0x90,62, 2,88, 0x92,53, 0x80, 
0x90,57, 2,88, 0x80, 0x82, 0x90,65, 0x92,53, 2,88, 0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x90,64, 0x91,48, 2,88, 
0x92,52, 2,88, 0x80, 0x90,60, 1,194, 0x80, 0x90,60, 0,150, 0x81, 0x82, 0x80, 0x90,36, 0x91,62, 
2,88, 0x92,52, 0x81, 0x91,58, 2,88, 0x81, 0x82, 0x91,67, 0x92,52, 2,88, 0x81, 0x80, 0x82, 0x90,65, 
0x91,41, 2,88, 0x92,53, 2,88, 0x80, 0x90,60, 1,194, 0x80, 0x90,60, 0,150, 0x81, 0x82, 0x80, 
0x90,41, 0x91,72, 2,88, 0x92,53, 0x81, 0x91,57, 2,88, 0x81, 0x82, 0x91,65, 0x92,53, 2,88, 
0x81, 0x80, 0x82, 0x90,64, 0x91,48, 2,88, 0x80, 0x81, 0x90,62, 0x91,50, 0x92,53, 2,13, 1,212, 
0x80, 0x90,70, 1,194, 0x80, 0x90,70, 0,75, 1,212, 0x80, 0x82, 0x81, 0x90,69, 0x91,41, 2,88, 
0x80, 0x90,53, 0x92,65, 2,88, 0x82, 0x81, 0x80, 0x90,67, 0x91,52, 0x92,58, 2,88, 0x80, 0x82, 0x81, 
0x90,65, 0x91,53, 0x92,57, 7,8, 0x80, 0x82, 0x81, 0xf0};
// This score contains 201 bytes, and 3 tone generators are used.
// 24 notes had to be skipped.



Playtune pt;

void setup() {

  // Enable all 3 NANO timers for notes that are output on digital pins 10, 11, and 12.
  // Those pins should be wired to 500-ohm resistors, the other ends of which should be connected together
  // to one terminal of an 8-ohm speaker.  The other terminal of the speaker should be connected to ground.  
  // No other hardware is needed!

  pt.tune_initchan (10); 
  pt.tune_initchan (11);
  pt.tune_initchan (12);
}

void loop () {
  pt.tune_playscore (score);  /* start playing */
  while (pt.tune_playing) ;   /* wait here until playing stops */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and re-installing arduino software seemed to work